# dmesg flooded with firewall logs

Tags: logs, iptables, rsyslog

In my iptables, I have a rule which logs dropped packets:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0       -j   LOG  --log-prefix "FW: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i eth0       -j   DROP
```

And in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, I have another rule which sends these logs to a dedicated file `/var/log/firewall.log`.

```
:msg, contains, "FW: "                    -/var/log/firewall.log
& ~
```

The `& ~` deletes the logs immediately, so that they don't flood `syslog` or other log files.

This works well, except that it floods `dmesg` with those firewall logs (not `/var/log/dmesg` but the output of command `dmesg`).

Is there a way to prevent these logs being shown in `dmesg` ?

Comment: What's the point in logging everything anyway?

Comment: It's really no good idea to log _all_ dropped packets.  Better thing than eliminating the symptoms would be being more specific with your logging rule.  E.g. it's not very wise to log any packets that are not related to any connection and don't do anything »special« (like connection initation).  Would be much better to cut this down to relevant things like »Host A wanted to connect to port B«.  Potentially the number of reasons a packet is dropped is massively greater than the number of reasons you would drop it for a _relevant_ reason.

Comment: @Andreas Wiese - I have simplified my rule for the sake of this question. My rules are more sophisticated and specific. But anyway, the question is how to prevent `dmesg` being flooded, not about firewall rules.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/954886/63361) about the Netfilter logging daemon `ulogd2`. That is how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `NFLOG` target instead of `LOG`:

```
NFLOG
    This target provides logging of matching packets. When this  target  is  set  for  a
    rule, the Linux kernel will pass the packet to the loaded logging backend to log the
    packet. This is usually used in combination with nfnetlink_log as  logging  backend,
    which  will multicast the packet through a netlink socket to the specified multicast
    group. One or more userspace processes may subscribe to the  group  to  receive  the
    packets.  Like  LOG, this is a non-terminating target, i.e. rule traversal continues
    at the next rule.
```

All you'd need is a `nfnetlink_log` capable logging program.  Messages would go there and the userspace process would decide whether to log the packet or not.

Another thing you could try would be limiting the `LOG` rule to a specific threshold:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m limit --limit 10/minutes -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

This would on average log 10 packets per minute.  You could of course adjust this at your needs.

Comment: I was not able to find any information how to configure `rsyslog` to log `NFLOG` packets. I need some solution that will work with `rsyslog`.

Comment: @MartinVegter - NFLOG will work with rsyslog.  For NFLOG, you would use ulogd (I think ulogd2 is needed) as the go-between.  It will listen on the netlink socket to get the logs, and deliver them (as configured) to syslog.  If ulogd2 is not available, use ulogd (1.x) and the ULOG target.

Answer (score 1):

When you have set the log level to 7 with the command:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0       -j   LOG  --log-prefix "FW: " --log-level 7
```

Then you can simply filter out these messages by passing the level threshold to the dmesg:

```
dmesg --level=err,warn
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the log-level you are using in iptables.  As I understand it from the rsyslog documentation log levels are: "The priority is one of the following keywords, in ascending order: debug, info, notice, warning, warn (same as warning), err, error (same as err), crit, alert, emerg, panic (same as emerg)."  What about trying to specify the log level in iptables by using its name, i.e. 'notice'.
Well serves me right for posting without checking as I now think that is not the issue at all.  I implemented a similar scheme to that outlined above and I get the same issue.  My centos 7 kernel is v3.10.0 and apparently since v3.5 it seems that kernel logging is done using /dev/kmsg and I presume dmesg somehow gets its input from there.

Answer (score -7):

Why do you care? `dmesg` is a low-level tool to print recent kernel messages, and you did ask for the kernel to log dropped packets.

Configure your system's syslog system to log iptables messages in a separate log file from other kernel messages, and use the log files that it writes instead of `dmesg`.

Comment: My opinion: I wondered if this comment was unfairly judged, because it did seem quite right/accurate advice.  However, this comment did come months after https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129028/97078 which provided rather specific information about how to implement this general advice, so this answer didn't seem to be very additionally-useful (at the time it was posted).